# Jasper Report Export PDF with Hibernate annotation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jasper-reports, hibernate-annotations

I am trying to generate PDF from jasperReport Library.

I tried some code but it only generates a PDF with some garbage valu or testing string which i have already set for testing.
My PDF look like this

> null null (ID: null) null

This is Demo for
Total 1 Page

here is my code for Purchase class

```
package org.chillies.database;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;    
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Index;
@Entity
public class Purchase {
private int id;
private String name;
private String companyName;
private double discount;
private String remark;
private List<SupplyOrder> supplyOrder = new ArrayList<SupplyOrder>();
private AddressDetails addressdetails;
private ContactDetails contactdetails;


public static final String KeypurchaseTable = "purchase";
private static final String Keyaddressjoincolumnname="addressIdfk";
private static final String Keycontactjoincolumnname="contactIdfk";

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name=Keyaddressjoincolumnname)
public AddressDetails getAddressdetails() {
    return addressdetails;
}

public void setAddressdetails(AddressDetails addressdetails) {
    this.addressdetails = addressdetails;
}

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name=Keycontactjoincolumnname)
public ContactDetails getContactdetails() {
    return contactdetails;
}

public void setContactdetails(ContactDetails contactdetails) {
    this.contactdetails = contactdetails;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int purchaseid) {
    this.id = purchaseid;
}

private static final String KeyinndexPurchaseName="indexPurchaseName";
@Index(name = KeyinndexPurchaseName)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public double getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(double discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}

public String getRemark() {
    return remark;
}

public void setRemark(String remark) {
    this.remark = remark;
}

@OneToMany(targetEntity = SupplyOrder.class, mappedBy = KeypurchaseTable, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<SupplyOrder> getSupplyOrder() {
    return supplyOrder;
}

public void setSupplyOrder(List<SupplyOrder> supplyOrder) {
    this.supplyOrder = supplyOrder;
}
}
```

class which generate PDF

```
package org.chillies.reports;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
public class JasperReportsIntro {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JasperReport jasperReport;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    try {
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jrxmls"
                + File.separator + "PurchaseReport.jrxml");
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
                "Genratedreports/simple_report.pdf");
        System.out.println("Completed");
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

my JRXML FILE PurchaseReport.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PurchaseesReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50" uuid="f050e3db-0847-4912-9c16-d6b157484813">
<import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
<style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="Calisto MT" fontSize="12"/>
<style name="Sans_Normal_Small" fontName="Calisto MT" fontSize="9"/>
<style name="Sans_Bold" fontName="Calisto MT" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
<style name="Sans_Italic" fontName="Calisto MT" fontSize="12" isItalic="true"/>
<parameter name="ReportTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString language="hql">
    <![CDATA[FROM Purchase]]>
</queryString>
<field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="discount" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[discount]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="remark" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[remark]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

<group name="PurchaseGroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="25">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="375" height="21" backcolor="#E0E0E0" uuid="a143642b-fbed-4962-bfbf-c9d9ecc24879"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="5" y="3" width="160" height="15" uuid="fdadafcd-6622-4d05-89f8-31eeb46e68f9"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name} + " " + $F{remark} + " (ID: " + $F{id} + ")"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="210" y="3" width="160" height="15" uuid="8e21ca6a-7eb9-4deb-8b36-9df9db27314c"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{discount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="25">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="475" height="1" forecolor="#808080" uuid="89aa8875-ef41-4ade-8143-b12e79955216"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Normal_Small" x="20" y="2" width="70" height="15" uuid="d248a006-9289-4a01-909d-81608bbdd09b"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Total]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Sans_Normal_Small" x="100" y="2" width="50" height="15" uuid="c4c43f7e-2ce3-4070-818b-e64bb6c27977"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PurchaseGroup_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<title>
    <band height="50">
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="515" height="1" forecolor="#000000" uuid="6a96d2fc-8ad1-4022-91e6-fcc11f3380f5"/>
        </line>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement style="Sans_Normal" x="0" y="10" width="515" height="30" uuid="876bd00a-1cd0-485e-8e71-20c402f03048"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                <font size="22"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{ReportTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="13">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement style="Sans_Normal_Small" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="20" y="0" width="70" height="12" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" printWhenGroupChanges="PurchaseGroup" uuid="8d08fcca-f5d3-4c5b-baa0-e5ab70628047"/>
            <text><![CDATA[This is Demo for Purchase List]]></text>
        </staticText>

    </band>
</detail>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="40">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION}.booleanValue()?Boolean.FALSE:Boolean.TRUE]]></printWhenExpression>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="515" height="1" uuid="7c3195dc-606d-4287-a159-acf9af1e1063"/>
        </line>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="200" y="20" width="80" height="15" uuid="dba281f2-0790-48c4-a5d8-0a71cfc4c842"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + String.valueOf($V{PAGE_NUMBER}) + " of"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="280" y="20" width="75" height="15" uuid="e6b4b6f0-e454-4c46-ad41-765e42ea01e8"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + String.valueOf($V{PAGE_NUMBER})]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```

Comment: Which version of of jasper report are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
package org.chillies.reports;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
public class JasperReportsIntro {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
    purchase.setName("Vivek");
    purchase.setRemark("This is remark");
    purchase.setDiscount(10.0);
    purchase.setId(20);
ArrayList<Purchase> list = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
        list.add(purchase);
        JRDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list);
JasperReport jasperReport;
JasperPrint jasperPrint;
try {
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jrxmls"
            + File.separator + "PurchaseReport.jrxml");
    jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), beanCollectionDataSource);
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,
            "Genratedreports/simple_report.pdf");
    System.out.println("Completed");
} catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Enjoy. :)

Comment: thanks you very much for your answer and i also found one solution for it all i need to do is just pass a hibernate session like this ---> 
   session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   model.put(JRHibernateQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_HIBERNATE_SESSION,session);
   jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, model);
   JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"Genratedreports/simple_report1.pdf");

Comment: It good that that you have solved it at your own end. If my answer is working fine, can you accept and upvote it?

Comment: yeah thanks buddy and your code is also working :)but you have to just change one line like this List<Purchase> list=new ArrayList<Purchase>();